# piping name of python script to python

Tags: python, bash, unix, terminal, pipe

I have a file in my directory called `foo.py` that contains Python code. How do I pipe the file to Python in the terminal so that Python will run it? Entering this into the terminal doesn't work:
`find -name foo.py -print | python`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-exec` parameter to find and execute all the founded `.py` files.

```
find -name '*.py' -exec python {} \;
```

And for a single file, you may use

```
find -name 'foo.py' -exec python {} \;
```

Note that this would search for the name `foo.py` in the current directory as well as the subdirectories.

Comment: And it's better to add `-type f` argument to the above find command.

Comment: This works, but I am wondering if there is a way to pipe it just out of curiosity, because it works if I pipe input to the script itself like so:  echo <some argument> | python foo.py

Comment: But it doesn't work with piping just the script name to python

Comment: try `find -name foo.py -print | xargs python`